# c++ embedded mono runtime compile time vs runtime

Tags: c#, c++, mono

I have embedded my C# DLL into my C++ application according to the documentation on http://www.mono-project.com/docs/advanced/embedding/.

On my build machine I run a different mono version than on the machine were the application is running.

I am wondering if the whole runtime is compiled into the executable or if this is just a wrapper to the installed runtime.

Is it save to use different versions of mono on the compile machine and on the runtime machine?

Comment: Why don't you install a version of mono for each of your target deploys and test your software on each version? http://download.mono-project.com/sources/mono/

Comment: The answer depends on how you're linking with Mono. Show us your build.